# Django MySQL Out of range value for column 'telephone' at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql, database, django, datatable

I looked everywhere to find a solution to this problem where I cannot type an integer of certain size.

In other posts, people suggested that I define a custom `BigInteger` class but that was not very helpful. Using the default `BigInteger` class from models doesn't seem to fix the problem either. It still gives me the error

> "Out of range value for column 'telephone' at row 1"

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix it??

Thanks!

Comment: What value are you trying to set, and did you recreate your schema with synbdb after changing the model definition?

Comment: Yes. So in my Model I have telephone = models.BigIntegerField() but whenever I type telephone number like 5107008465 and create an user with that telephone, it complains with the message above. I have tried to drop the table by sqlclear and recreated the schema with syncdb but it wasn't successful.

Comment: `sqlclear` will only print out the `DROP TABLE` syntax, it won't actually execute it for you.

Comment: Then do I have to login to mysql and do it manually?

Comment: When I do "python manage.py sqlclear food" where food is the name of the table, it just prints out "BEGIN;
DROP TABLE `food_favs`;
DROP TABLE `food_user`;
COMMIT;"   But when I login to mysql and type DROP TABLE 'food_user'; it says no database selected....

Comment: You need to choose a database first: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually save phone numbers as a string (CharField). If you later use international phone numbers, a number such as "+15554441234" should be valid. That's why I think strings are a better choice.